# Range.Find method returning unexpected value

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

This is strange. According to MSDN (and several questions on StackOverflow), the Range.Find method in VBA is supposed to return `Nothing` when the specified value is not found in the specified range. However, when I run the following code, if the value is not found, the Range.Find method doesn't return `Nothing`. It doesn't return *anything*.

Please assume all variables are properly defined. VBA is in an Access 2013 module with Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library referenced.

```
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim rngFound As Excel.Range
' ...
For i = 0 To UBound(strHeader)
    Set rngFound = rng.Find( _
        What:=strHeader(i), _
        After:=rng(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        MatchCase:=True _
    )
    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
        bolValid = False
        Exit For
    ElseIf i = UBound(strHeader) Then
        bolValid = True
    End If
Next i
```

If the string in `strHeader(i)` isn't found in range `rng`, then the variable `rngFound` should be set to `Nothing`. But, it's not.

Suppose the value of `rngFound.Address` from an earlier iteration is "$J$1". Now suppose that the value of the current iteration is not found in `rng`. Range.Find *should* return `Nothing`, but when queried in the Immediate window, `rngFound.Address` is still "$J$1".

Any idea what might be causing this odd behaviour?

**Edit:** Full function code, as requested.

```
Private Function CheckIntegrity(FileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim rngFound As Excel.Range
    Dim strHeader() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim bolValid As Boolean

    On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

    ReDim strHeader(9)
    strHeader(0) = "String1"
    strHeader(1) = "String2"
    strHeader(2) = "String3"
    strHeader(3) = "String4"
    strHeader(4) = "String5"
    strHeader(5) = "String6"
    strHeader(6) = "String7"
    strHeader(7) = "String8"
    strHeader(8) = "String9"
    strHeader(9) = "String10"

    Set wb = OpenWorkbook(FileName, True)
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then Set rng = ws.Range("A1:Z1")

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For i = 0 To Ubound(strHeader)
            Set rngFound = rng.Find( _
                What:=strHeader(i), _
                After:=rng(rng.Cells.Count), _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                MatchCase:=True _
            )
            If rngFound Is Nothing Then
                bolValid = False
                Exit For
            ElseIf i = Ubound(strHeader) Then
                bolValid = True
            End If
        Next i
    End If

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    CheckIntegrity = bolValid
    PROC_EXIT:
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rngFound = Nothing
    Erase strHeader
    i = 0
    bolValid = False
    Exit Function

    PROC_ERR:
    MsgBox "Error encountered. " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume PROC_EXIT
End Function
```

The value of rngFound is not being set to `Nothing` if the element of strHeader is not found.

Comment: How do you know `rngFound` is not `Nothing`, what does it mean _It doesn't return anything._ -> every variable does have a value. What is the purpose of using `After:=rng(rng.Cells.Count)` as starting point?

Comment: Returns `Nothing` for me when no match is made. Which line are you stopped on when you query from the Immediate window?

Comment: @TimWilliams It's stopped on the line `If rngFound Is Nothing Then` when I query the immediate window.

Comment: @user3964075 I know Range.Find is not returning `Nothing`, because the value of `rngFound` is not `Nothing` on the line `If rngFound Is Nothing Then` after the Range.Find method has searched for something I know is not there. The purpose of the `After:=...` parameter is so that the first cell of the range `rng` is searched.

Comment: I've never seen that behavior, and I can't replicate what you're seeing.  Care to share your entire code?

Comment: @TimWilliams Entire function code added.

Comment: Using your full code and running from Word, I put a break on `bolValid = False` and made sure there was one "no match" in the lookup row: I still get rngFound=Nothing when the run breaks on that line.

Comment: Also ran from access - same deal there as running from Excel or Word.  Something is wrong in your setup.

Comment: After:=rng(rng.Cells.Count) seems redundant I tried it and it works with or without it.

Comment: Are you using this as a worksheet function with an early version of Excel? (Find does not work in a UDF in versions before XL 2002)

Comment: @CharlesWilliams Excel 2013 is installed. This function is part of a larger code module in an Access 2013 database (.accdb).

Answer (score 1):

Solved. After some other errors started popping up, I performed a "repair" on my Microsoft Office installation in the Windows Control Panel, and the problem from this question apparently fixed itself. Same code as above works fine now.

Thanks for the help, everyone, but I think it was simply a matter of a pooched Office installation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Option Compare Database
 Sub test()
 Dim bolValid As Boolean
 Dim rng As Excel.Range
 Dim rngFound As Excel.Range
 Dim strHeader() As Variant
 ' ...
 Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open("M:\My Documents\Heat Trace\Macro    Workbooks\StackOverflow\test1.xlsx")
 wb.Application.Visible = True
 Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set rng = Range("A1:A1")

 strHeader() = Array("this", "again")
 For i = 0 To UBound(strHeader)
     Set rngFound = rng.Find( _
         What:=strHeader(i), _
         After:=rng(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count), _
         LookAt:=xlWhole, _
         MatchCase:=True _
     )
     If rngFound Is Nothing Then
         bolValid = False
         Exit For
     ElseIf i = UBound(strHeader) Then
         bolValid = True
     End If
 Next i

 Set rng = Nothing
 Set ws = Nothing
 wb.Close
 Set wb = Nothing


 End Sub
```

The above worked for me. I had to add the Microsoft Excel reference to use Excel.Range etc. Try it out.

Thanks